# SparkSQL UDF Registration in Java8

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.3.0 on Java 8.  I've got no issues setting up my SQLContext and creating dataframes, the spark DSL is pretty smooth.  But I want to use a custom UDF.

According to the spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala

`sqlCtx.udf().register("strLen", (String s) -> { s.length(); });`

Should do it for registering a UDF.  But my IDE (IntelliJ) complains:

`Cannot resolve method 'register(java.lang.String, <lambda expression>)'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the documentation & the code documentation are a bit out of sync on this one, and I tend to go with the in-code documentation just because its often right there when the developer is making the updates. Looking in the JavaUDFSuite I'd try:

```
sqlContext.udf().register(
   "stringLengthTest", (String str) -> str.length(), DataTypes.IntegerType);
```